# Why is my material not reflecting as much light as it should?

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, reflection

I was following a tutorial online and noticed that my material wasn't reflecting as much light as it should. I've attached a picture of what mine looks like and a picture of what it's supposed to look like, and also have attached a picture of my shading tab. Does anyone know why this is happening? I am using eevee rendering engine.

Here's the link to the tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y0DMMwwdBaY

Link to my file:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GsRNoZoIG8D8B7N4-VugBzFIjvOJj7a-?usp=sharing

I tried to label my images but it didn't work, sorry.

[image: Here's what my sword looks like]

[image: Here's what the sword is supposed to look like]

[image: Here's my shading tab]

Comment: Hard to tell without the file, in the screenshot it simply looks like the sword below has light shining directly on it, while your sword above is standing in the shadow (the bright spot on the ground is in front of the sword, which is stuck in shadowed ground).

Comment: Upload your blend file here: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @Luciano they've changed that domain to https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I think the problem is the placement of the rocks, because that creates the hole that the light enters through, creating the shaft of light effect.  But I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Indeed it's the placement of the light : as you can see from the placement of the area that is lit on the rock (bottom left of your image) the sword is not in light. It's in the shade. Fix : rotate your environment or your light source so the cast light hits the sword